# ElasticsearchWarning: [types removal] Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated, use the typeless endpoints instead

Tags: python, elasticsearch

What typeless endpoint should I use in my script, I want to index the json files in a given directory. Getting a slight error, searched a lot but got no clue.
The full error:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py:209: ElasticsearchWarning: [types removal] Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated, use the typeless endpoints instead (/{index}/_doc/{id}, /{index}/_doc, or /{index}/_create/{id}).
  warnings.warn(message, category=ElasticsearchWarning)
```

My script:

```
import requests, json, os
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

#folder containing the json folders of scraped data
directory = '../spider/'

#Elasticsearch instance will listen on port 9200
res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
print (res.content)
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': '9200'}])

#index value object to iterate over the JSON files
i = 1

#Iterate over each JSON file and load it into Elasticsearch
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        fullpath=os.path.join(directory, filename)
        f = open(fullpath)
        docket_content = f.read()
        # Send the data into es
        es.index(index='myIndex', ignore=400, doc_type='docket', id=i, document=json.loads(docket_content),)
        i = i + 1
```

This is my first time trying out Elasticsearch, I am dumb and solutions are appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change `doc_type='docket'` to `doc_type='_doc'` and it'll work with what you have

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/removal-of-types.html goes into it more, are it's a deprecated approach

Comment: Thank you, it worked, no longer an error. Finally could you please tell how can I view the index from Kibana? The index, myIndex isn't there yet, shouldn't I be able to view the index from there?

Comment: Or at the very least, how do I confirm that this index has been made through the script on Elasticsearch?